# Is there a way of extracting a value from a column alongside grouped columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am analysing a file using Dataframes that I have grouped by vendor and most recent date. I now need to extract a score that corresponds to the most recent date.

The Dataframe (work_data) looks like this:

ACTIVITY DATE FACILITY CITY  FACILITY NAME  \
0           2018      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS
1           2018      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS
2           2018      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS
3           2017      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS
4           2017      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS
5           2017      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS
6           2017      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS
7           2017      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS
8           2017      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS
9           2017      TORRANCE  DREAM DINNERS

```
                      PE DESCRIPTION PROGRAM STATUS  SCORE SERIAL NUMBER  \
```

0  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   97.0     DA2FXQNN6
1  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   97.0     DA2FXQNN6
2  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   97.0     DA2FXQNN6
3  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   95.0     DACP43IQW
4  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   95.0     DACP43IQW
5  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   95.0     DACP43IQW
6  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   95.0     DACP43IQW
7  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   95.0     DACP43IQW
8  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   96.0     DAEMVMRBY
9  RESTAURANT (0-30) SEATS MODERATE RISK         ACTIVE   96.0     DAEMVMRBY

```
                  _id_x VIOLATION CODE  \
```

0  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84b           F048
1  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84b           F046
2  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84b           F033
3  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84c           F048
4  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84c           F044
5  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84c           F040
6  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84c           F035
7  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84c           F034
8  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84d           F037
9  5d39d1f0f2134bd98132b84d           F035

```
                           VIOLATION DESCRIPTION                     _id_y
```

0                            # 47. Permits Available  5d33fdad3569b9ef86dbbff6
1  # 46. Signs posted; last inspection report ava...  5d33fdad3569b9ef86dbbff7
2  # 33. Nonfood-contact surfaces clean and in go...  5d33fdad3569b9ef86dbbff8
3                            # 47. Permits Available  5d33fdaf3569b9ef86deab10
4  # 44. Floors, walls and ceilings: properly bui...  5d33fdaf3569b9ef86deab11
5  # 40. Plumbing: Plumbing in good repair, prope...  5d33fdaf3569b9ef86deab12
6  # 35. Equipment/Utensils - approved; installed...  5d33fdaf3569b9ef86deab13
7  # 34. Warewashing facilities: Adequate, mainta...  5d33fdaf3569b9ef86deab14
8  # 37. Adequate ventilation and lighting; desig...  5d33fdaf3569b9ef86df905f
9  # 35. Equipment/Utensils - approved; installed...  5d33fdaf35
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DrFs.png)

I have tried to groupby.max() on the year but can't work out I extract the score column.

I have tried:

```
corr_group = work_data[['ACTIVITY DATE','FACILITY NAME','SCORE']].groupby(['FACILITY NAME']).agg({
    'ACTIVITY DATE':'max',
    'FACILITY NAME':'count',
    'SCORE'
    })
```

and also  tried having a function that iterates through:

```
def high_score():
    corr_group['High_Score'] = 1
    for row in work_data:
        if (work_data['ACTIVITY DATE']==corr_group['ACTIVITY DATE'] 
        and work_data['FACILITY NAME']==corr_group['FACILITY NAME']):
            corr_group['High_Score']=work_data['SCORE']
```

Comment: Do not put picture of dataset only. Please recover the original data.

Comment: @QuangHoang do you mean like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the date column to timestamp

```
 df['ACTIVITY DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['ACTIVITY DATE'])
```

Then group by vendor and use max()

```
df_grouped=df.groupby(['FACILITY NAME'])[['SCORE','ACTIVITY DATE']].max()
```

Alternatively, you can use a pivot table, make sure to sort 'ACTIVITY DATE' in descending order and then take the first line from each group

```
df.sort_values(by='ACTIVITY DATE',inplace=True,ascending=False)
df_pivot=df.pivot_table(index=['FACILITY NAME'],values=['SCORE','ACTIVITY DATE'],aggfunc='first')
```

Comment: thanks for the response but its not quite what I am after  - I don't want the max score but the score from the most recent (ie max year)

Comment: Doesn't this give you the max for both year and corresponding score? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: No I need the max year and the corresponding score for that year. I’ve tried using .agg to return different types for different columns but it doesn’t work because I dint want to do any calculation on the score field.

Comment: I added an alternate approach